# SQL sort with null values included

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sorting

I tried the following query to sort along with the NULL entries in table. I need to sort by book_name with the book_id.

For ascending:

```
SELECT book_id 
FROM   books 
GROUP  BY book_id 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN book_id IS NULL THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
          END, 
          book_id; 

 1 
 2 
 NULL
```

**Expected Result :**

For ascending:

```
1
2
NULL
```

For descending:

```
SELECT book_id 
FROM   books 
GROUP  BY book_id 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN book_id IS NULL THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
          END DESC, 
          book_id; 




 NULL
 1 
 2
```

**Expected Result :**

For descending:

```
NULL
2
1
```

Comment: `order by 
 case when book_id is null then 1 else 0 end desc, book_id desc; 
`

Comment: Save some typing `order by case when book_id is null then 0 else 1 end, book_id desc`.

Comment: Are you looking for code for both MySQL and MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not directly involved...)

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply the `DESC` sort direction to the second sort column:

```
SELECT book_id 
FROM   books 
GROUP  BY book_id 
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN book_id IS NULL 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
          END DESC, 
          book_id DESC; --- !!!
```

If you omit it default is `ASC`

Answer (score 0):

just set the null values to -1 then order based on that. For example

```
 SELECT book_id 
FROM   books 
GROUP  BY book_id 
ORDER  BY isnull(book_id,-1) ASC;
```

Comment: Is `isnull()` for MySQL or MS SQL Server or both?

Comment: Won;t this put `NULL` values at the bottom?

Comment: my mistake, I thought we were on about MSSql and Felix ASC would be correct one to use in this example you're right

Comment: Still, this would sort non-null `book_id`s in ascending order. OP wants to sort it in descending order, with `NULL` values at the top.

Answer (score 0):

ASC:

```
SELECT book_id 
FROM   books
order by book_id , COALESCE(book_id,0);
```

DESC:

```
SELECT book_id 
FROM   books
order by book_id desc , COALESCE(book_id,0) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below queries-

**For Ascending**

```
SELECT book_id 
FROM   books 
GROUP  BY book_id 
ORDER  BY IF(book_id IS NULL,1,0), book_id;
```

**For descending**

```
SELECT book_id 
FROM   books 
GROUP  BY book_id 
ORDER  BY IF(book_id IS NULL,0,1), book_id DESC;
```